# How do I reset the OpenFileDialog (WPF) initial directory?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I'm writing a plug-in to a parent application (outside my control). My plug-in uses `OpenFileDialog` (WPF) to allow the user to select a file. When the user is done with my plug-in, he or she will continue to use the parent application. The user's interaction with the parent application also includes selecting a file.

The problem is that the initial directory of the parent application's open file dialog box is the last directory used by my plug-in (I'm guessing it also uses `OpenFileDialog`). Is there a way to reset or revert the directory chosen in my plug-in so it doesn't affect the initial directory in the parent application? I have tried `Reset()` and `RestoreDirectory = true` (via the `OpenFileDialog`) but neither works.

If there's no solution with the WPF `OpenFileDialog`, then I'm open to third-party open file dialogs. I'd appreciate any recommendations.

Comment: You can write your own class that inherits from OpenFileDialog where the only difference is an internal property that keeps track of the original Initial directory and restore it when the form closes.

Comment: Did you tried to reset the directory after usage?

Comment: Set the InitialDirectory property on the dialogue to whichever folder you prefer.

Comment: @Steve I'm not sure how this will help me. I don't have control over the parent application's open file dialog.

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg Yes, I tried it before and after. Neither way works.

Comment: @Andy I can do that for my plug-in file dialog but not for the parent application's.

Comment: did you tried RestoreDirectory like it described in this documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.restoredirectory?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_FileDialog_RestoreDirectory or this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c43ddefb-1274-4ceb-9cda-c78d860b687c/how-to-get-the-last-directory-after-open-filedialog?forum=csharpgeneral , you need to set it to true before you open the dialog so the directory you chose will not be saved on the "Environment.CurrentDirectory"

Comment: @YairI Correct, I tried that and it doesn't work. It continues to use the directory from the last open file dialog.

Comment: what about getting the "Environment.CurrentDirectory" and save it before opening the dialog and setting it back after the dialog is closed?

Comment: @YairI Setting it back with `InitialDirectory`? It doesn't work with that property.

Comment: No, I meant setting this "Environment.CurrentDirectory" back. not the "InitialDirectory" of the dialog. from what i read on the answer here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c43ddefb-1274-4ceb-9cda-c78d860b687c/how-to-get-the-last-directory-after-open-filedialog?forum=csharpgeneral the Environment.CurrentDirectory saves the last the directory.

Comment: @YairI Tried it. Didn't work. :(